# How to export components like Row, Col from antd library in my custom library without any change?

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am creating new library for react, say `custom-ant-lib` which imports `antd` and contains overrides for components like `button`, `modal` etc...

In my app I want to use components like `Row` & `Col` which are components of `antd` library.

I have already imported `antd` in `custom-ant-lib`.
I have imported `custom-ant-lib` in my app.

So importing `antd` again in my app for `Row` & `Col` will cause redundancy and additional import.

**Current status**: I import both `antd` and `custom-ant-lib` in my JSX file to use various components.

**Expected**: I should be able to skip `antd` import and use components of `antd` from `custom-ant-lib`, also I do not want to override or change any thing for `Row` and `Col` but should be able to export them.

[ant docs link](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce) :- https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce

e.g current JSX:

`import {Row, Col} from 'ant'
 import {Button} from 'custom-ant-lib'`

expected JSX:

`import {Row, Col, Button} from 'custom-ant-lib'`

Is there any way to skip import `antd` use them indirectly through `custom-ant-lib`?

Comment: Hi Prajesh, I am trying to do something similar. Did you find any solution for this? Did you make your custom AntD library?

Answer (score 1):

In 'custom-ant-lib' module, Do something like:

```
import {Row, Col} from 'ant'
...rest of code
export {Row, Col, Button}
```

Comment: This works but not completely. e.g styles for Menu/Layout components do not get applied in app.

Answer (score -2):

In your custom library, you can use something like

```
export * from "ant"
```

Then all components from ant should be accessible in your application through your custom ant lib.

Comment: here comes the tricky part.
If you do as mentioned above then while building package there will surely come a ambiguity error as I am also exporting my changes with couple of ant components.